# Count query with results from a query

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

i have the following problem.

I have this SQL query:

```
select id, tableid 
    from sysclass 
    where id in (
        select contentid 
            from sysclassgroupcontent 
            where groupid = 5 AND contenttype != 1
        );
```

The Result is for example:

```
ID   TableID
1    200
2    300
3    200
```

Now i want to insert in this query how many items are in these particular tables where id equals the id and the tableid

in code:

```
select Count(*) from xxx where classid = yyy;
```

XXX is the tableid e.g. 200 and yyy is die ID e.g. 1 or 2.

the result should look like:

```
ID   TableID   Count
    1    200   1020
    2    300   50021
    3    200   13
```

Here is the Table structure:

Table SysClasss:

- Id(PK)
- TableId (FK - refering to SysTable.Id)

Table SysClassContents:

- Id (PK)
- GroupId (FK refering to SysClassGroup.Id)
- ContentID (FK - regering to SysClass.Id)

Table SysClassGroup:

- Id(PK)

Table SysTable:

- Id(PK)
- Name (these are the Names of the different tables i want to count in) e.g. tabelID =200 == LvElements

Now i want to count in the table LVElements all Items with classid = 1 if its in the Sysclassgroup = 5
Is this possible in one query and how?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: please post your table schemas

Comment: @Melon:
Table SysClass has the Fields: Id(PK), TableId (FK - refering to SysTable.Id)

Table SysClassContent has the Fields: Id (PK), GroupId (FK refering to SysClassGroup.Id), ContentID (FK - regering to SysClass.Id)

Table SysClassGroup has the Fields: Id(PK)

Table SysTable has the Fields: Id(PK), Name (these are the Names of the different tables i want to count in)
e.g. tabelID =200 == LvElements. No i want to count in the table LVElements all Items.

Comment: ah.. and in every table there is a field with classes which consist to this table. e.g. Table "LvElements" consists of Classrd 1 and 3

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to

```
GROUP BY ID
```

it will give result what you want

Answer (score 0):

Hm, i think the only way to do this is with a mysql procedure, since it's not really possible to use "dynamic" table names directly in the statement.

Trie something like that:

Edit - added delimiter rows:

```
delimiter //     
CREATE PROCEDURE getTableCount(IN argTableName CHAR(64), IN argClassid CHAR(64))
    BEGIN
        SET @s = CONCAT('SELECT count(*) FROM XP_net.',argTableName,' WHERE classid = ', argClassid );
        PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
        EXECUTE stmt;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
    END
//
delimiter ;
```

Then call it in your statement with this:

EDIT - Added join:

```
select sysclass.id, sysclass.tableid, getTableCount(SysTable.Name, 'xxx') as count
    from sysclass, SysTable:
    where id in (
        select contentid 
            from sysclassgroupcontent 
            where groupid = 5 AND contenttype != 1
        )
    and SysTable.ID = sysclass.tableid;
```

Comment: thank you. so you think that the only to do this is manually?

Comment: No not really manually, because after creating the procedure you can always use it. You just have to create it once. After that you can simple use the select statement as shown.

Comment: Its not working: Fehler(1,25): PLS-00103: Fand das Symbol "IN" als eines der folgenden erwartet wurde:     <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier>    current delete exists prior 

Sorry its german.

So there is not the possiblity to get all counts at once?

Comment: here are the table schemas:

Comment: Table SysClass has the Fields: Id(PK), TableId (FK - refering to SysTable.Id) Table SysClassContent has the Fields: Id (PK), GroupId (FK refering to SysClassGroup.Id), ContentID (FK - regering to SysClass.Id) Table SysClassGroup has the Fields: Id(PK) Table SysTable has the Fields: Id(PK), Name (these are the Names of the different tables i want to count in) e.g. tabelID =200 == LvElements. No i want to count in the table LVElements all Items

Comment: Please can you edit your question and add this schema? I think there ist it better readable. Do you created the procedure in a correct way? I've not wrote down all the necessary things => http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-procedure.html

Comment: No i think it's not possible to get all counts at once. Just with using a (prepared) subquery / procedure call for each row. But maybe someone have a better idea.

Comment: ok - did you see the table structure above. the table number could not be used to get the count - the table name is important. how do i need to change your procedure?

Comment: A, the name is in the sysTable? Just just have to extend the select query with a join, I've edited my post.

Comment: Still not working. the "table" in the procedure is wrong. SQl is expecting an identifier.

ok i think my table names are confusing.
In the table SysTable there are fields: ID and Name
e.g. 200 with the Name LvElement
Now i want to count all entries in the table XP_net.LVElement where classId = result from the first query where i searched a classgroup for their content. Can you follow? :)

Comment: Ok but XP_net is just your Schema name. Means LvElement is really da table, and not a Column. :D If yes add it to concat command: SET @s = CONCAT('SELECT count(*) FROM XP_net.',table,' WHERE classid = ', classid ). I mean the 'xxx' in ther query iss just a placeholder for your classgroup. But basically this should work, if I've understand all correctly :D Please can you past in the exact exception?

Comment: and why do you use the Concat function? i dont get it

Comment: Just to build up the query. ;)

Comment: hm try maybe another variable name than "table". Could be a reserved name from mysql^^ use "argTable" or something else

Comment: I've edited my post to use other variable names. classid is a number?

Comment: i tried something else:
`Select sysclass.id, systable.name
From sysclass INNER JOIN systable
ON sysclass.tableid = systable.id
where id in (
        select contentid 
            from sysclassgroupcontent 
            where groupid = 5 AND contenttype != 1
        );`
why does this not work?

Comment: I've tried now to define the procedure. When setting the delimiter to something else then ; (this is done with the row "delimiter //") I'm able to create it. So whats corrently wrong with?

Comment: Regarding your query, you have to add the table name bevor "id", otherwise mysql doesn't know which id colum do you want ;)

Comment: ah ok. thx. but the procedure is still not working. PLS-00103 something with "IN"

Comment: how and where do you try to create the procedure? Btw. which mysql version do you use? ^^ Procedures are just possible > 5.0

Comment: i use the sql developer with a oracle db

Comment: können wir auch deutsch sprechen?

Comment: ARGL why do you tag this with mysql? :P Oracle procedur is build up completely differently. (Könnten wir, muss aber jetzt leider weg, kann erst am abend wieder helfen. Guck mal google wie man oracle proceduren baut ;) )

Comment: Hey. Ah sorry. Ich hab davon keine Ahnung :)
Also nochmal zum Verstänis: 
Am liebsten wäre mir ein code, der mir direkt für jede Klasse die Anzahl der Reihen ausgibt. Jede Klasse gehört zu einer bestimmten Tabelle. Kann ich nicht diese (meine letzte Anweisung mit dem Join) speichern und diese dann für jede Reihe abarbeiten?

Comment: Ja das ist schon eine wichtige Erwähnung, in jeder Datenbank werden die Sachen etwas anders definiert ;) Leider. Mit Oracle Procedures kenne ich mich leider auch nicht so aus, aber ich denk mit dem Hinweis von mir was du machen sollst müsstest du es bei erGooglen können. Also die schönerer und schnellere Möglichkeit ist eben die Stored Procedure, wo du einfach jedesmal mit dem übegebenen Tabellennamen ein Prepared Statement bastelst und ausführst.

Comment: Möglichkeit zwei, wohl für dich einfacher, ist wenn du einfach In deinem Source Code halt in einer Schleife dann das Count Query ausführst. Nur mit einem Join ist das leider nicht machbar. :/

Comment: Hey. danke für die Antwort. Mit der Schleife habe ich das auch gedacht, aber wie funktioniert so eine Schleife in SQL?

Comment: Ne nicht in SQL, in deinem Programm, keine Ahnung, was hast du da, Java, Php, C? Wirst ja wohl irgendeine Software schreiben?